# How to remove an item from a java List transformed from string[]?

Tags: java, string, list

```
String line = "5 1973 2205 2396 2406";
String[] paperids = line.split(" ");
List<String> paperList = Arrays.asList(paperids);
paperList.remove(0);
```

This is my Java code, I want to transfer the string[] to List and remove the first item of  List, but it doesn't work in the last line, could someone help me ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The string "it doesn't work" is not a built-in error message in Java.

Comment: if you spent 5 seconds reading the javadoc of Arrays.asList, it would answer your question.

Answer (score 8):

The `List` returned from `Arrays.asList` is not mutable (it can't be changed).  This is actually an (annoying) feature of `List`

Try creating an `ArrayList` and seeding it with the array values

```
String line = "5 1973 2205 2396 2406";
String[] paperids = line.split(" ");
List<String> paperList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(paperids));
paperList.remove(0);
```

Comment: +1 It is really annoying... Can you tell me what could be the reason behind it?

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder Why `List` allows `add` to be a "optional" operation is beyond me (it is documented as such though). If I had been designing it (not that I had that much experience or knowledge back them), I would have had a `List` that defined all the getters and a `MutableList` that defined all the setters, less confusion that way ;)

Comment: The answer is correct but the first sentence is not. The list is not immutable, it is just a fixed size. This is because it's backed by a Java array and arrays in Java are not resizable. Did anybody here read the javadoc? :)

Comment: @sjr So it can't be changed then?

Comment: Its size cannot be changed. Have you heard of List.set? Changes of that nature will be written through to the array.

Comment: @sjr Personally, I still call the list non-mutable.  While the contents might be changed, the actually list can't.  To me, it semantics over word play. From the perspective of the question, the list is immutable and needs to wrapped in such away that it can be altered.

Comment: you have a funny definition of mutable

Comment: @sjr think of the list as a container. The container it self is not mutable, nothing can be added or removed from it. However, the existing contents can still be changed - semantics ;) - ps I should add that I agree with you and your point is valid